# Iff $\{s t^{-1}: s, t \in T \} = G$ for a group $G$ and a nonempty subset $T$, then each right coset $Ng$ of $G$ is already trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $T \subseteq G, T ≠ \emptyset$. We now want to consider the set $T T^{-1} := \{s t^{-1}: s, t \in T \}$.

I now want to show that $\langle T T^{-1} \rangle ≠ G $ iff there exists a subgroup $N ≤ G$ aswell as a $g \in G$, so that $T \subseteq N g \subsetneq G$ (with $N g$ being the right coset).

I must admit that I'm having trouble finding a good approach so far. If we have that $\langle T T^{-1} \rangle = G$, then for each $h \in G$, we have that $g = a_1^{k_1} \cdot ... \cdot a_n^{k_n}$ for some $a_1, ..., a_n \in T T^{-1}$, and per definition of $T T^{-1}$, we have that $a_i = s_i t_i^{-1}$ for some $s_i, t_i \in T$, and for all $i$.

Now, how would I continue from there? I need to show that that in case such a decomposition exists for each element $h \in G$, we have that $N g = G$ for each subgroup $N ≤ G$, and for each $g \in G$. Now I guess that with the decomposition for $h \in G$ given above, we somehow need to show that $h$ also already lies in within $N g$. But I don't know how I could achieve that result.

Vice versa, if we already have that each coset $N g$ with $T \subseteq N g$ is equal to $G$, then it would be sufficient to find a decomposition for any $g \in G$ into the elements of $T T^{-1}$. But even in that direction, I don't really know how to continue.

(If this problem has already been posted somewhere, then I'd appreciate being linked to it – since I didn't know any concrete keywords to type in, I subsequently couldn't find anything that's related closely enough.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $t\in T$. Note that $T\subseteq TT^{-1}t$. (Indeed, if $x\in T$, then $x=xt^{-1}t$.) So, if $\langle TT^{-1}\rangle< G$, then take $N=\langle TT^{-1}\rangle$ and $g=t$. We have $T\subseteq TT^{-1}t\subseteq \langle TT^{-1}\rangle t=Ng\subset G$.

Conversely, if $T\subseteq Ng$ for some $N<G$, then $T^{-1}\subseteq g^{-1}N$ hence $TT^{-1}\subseteq Ngg^{-1}N=N$ and thus $\langle TT^{-1}\rangle\leq N <G$, as desired.

Comment: I know that I've already accepted your answer, but I hope you can still help me with one point. I first didn't notice it but now I'm struggling with one step of your solution. How do we know that $T \subseteq \langle T T^{-1} \rangle$? Because $T$ doesn't necessarily need to contain the neutral group element, so can we really always choose a $t \in T$, so that $s t^{-1} = s$ lies in $T T^{-1}$ for any $s \in T$? (Because if we don't know that, then I'm afraid both of your directions don't work that easily, do they?)

Comment: Actually, if we choose $T = \{g\}, g ≠ e_G$, then we have that $T T^{-1} = \{g g^{-1}\} = \{e_G\}$, therefore (unless I'm missing something), $T$ generally isn't a subset of $T T^{-1}$. (As written in the question, $T$ isn't a subgroup but just a subset of $G$. If it were to contain the neutral element, then we would obviously have that $T \subseteq T T^{-1}$.) (For that reason, I've removed the accepted-mark on your answer for now, and with the intention of not discouraging other potential responses.) Is there maybe an easy "fix" or so that still makes your solution work?

Comment: You're right, we don't necessarily have $T\subseteq \langle TT^{-1}\rangle$. The converse is still fine though. I'll see if I can fix the first one.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes, the second part of your answer still holds, as far as I can see.

Comment: How about this?

Comment: I think it works now. Thanks again :)